# Ruby multi hash random value

Tags: ruby, random, hash

`countries = Hash[
    "north" =>
        "nl",
        "no",
        "uk"
    "south" =>
        "sp",
        "fr",
        "it"
    "east" =>
        "ru",
        "bl",
        "bg"
]`

How can I get a random value for each element (north, south, east)?

thank you very much

Comment: You `countries` hash is not a proper Hash syntax although.

Comment: Note that `v.sample` is the same as `v[rand(v.size)]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using [`Array#sample`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) :

```
countries = {"north" => ["nl", "no", "uk"], "south" => ["sp", "fr", "it"], "east" => ["ru", "bl", "bg"] }
countries.map { |_,v| v.sample } # => ["nl", "it", "bg"]
countries.map { |_,v| v.sample } # => ["uk", "it", "bg"]
```

Comment: A good practice is to use `|_,v|` to avoid creating an unused local variable.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes, First I did `|k,v|`, after that your sentence came into my brain, so I removed `k`, and made it as `|_,v|`. Thanks for the review.

Comment: Ok, thanks!

countries.map { |_,v| v.sample }.each do |variable|
  puts variable
end

And how can I print every element (north,south,east) for each loop?
ie. puts "{#...} #{variable}"

Comment: @user476918 `countries.map { |k, v| [k, v.sample] }` returns an array of element/random country pairs

Comment: @user476918 or do `countries.each { |k, v| p [k, v.sample] }`

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to Arup's answer.

```
countries = {"north" => ["nl", "no", "uk"], "south" => ["sp", "fr", "it"], "east" => ["ru", "bl", "bg"]}
countries.values.map(&:sample)
```